# Looking for best way to write math notes using Latex and markdown

Tags: editors, markdown, ide

I am currently looking for a way to take math note using latex and markdown.
The features what I want are

1. Real Time Preview (so I don't need to save it to preview)
2. Can define macros
3. Can use packages of Latex such as amsmath

Since Latex itself is compile-language, most of the options are not real time. Therefore, I think markdown with Latex can be a solution. However, I can't find an option that supports all three of them. I tried...

1. VScode with markdown+math extension (Use Katex, meaning 3 is not satisfied)
2. Atom with markdown preview plus extension (seems 3 is not satisfied)
3. [edit] I tried Overleaf with autocompile with fast option. (the compile time is too slow. meaning it is essentially not a real time preview)

[edit]
The real time preview I want is something like the following.
[image]

Could you please help for this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Overleaf with autocompile seems to satisfy all three, see https://www.overleaf.com/blog/642-tip-of-the-week-overleaf-v2-autocompile.

Comment: I actually tried that option but it is so slow that it is not a real time preview actually. That is why I think about markdown+latex option because option 1 and 2 satisfied real time preview pretty well.

Comment: You can include markdown environments in your latex document if you load the markdown package. The outlines package provides concise syntax for creating list-type environments.

Comment: Well, that is still very slow because I need to compile the whole document. The meaning of markdown+latex is actually creating markdown file and use latex syntax in markdown. Since markdown is a markup language that doesn't need compilation, this way supports the real time preview very well. But I can't find a way that satisfies all three requirements above.

Comment: What platform are you on? Aquamacs (OS X Emacs port) includes a preview feature that shows in-line math snippets formatted which might meet your needs.

Comment: What specific packages (or parts of amsmath) are you wanting to use?  I would think you could just go with LaTeX with no packages during the realtime, and then afterward worry about making it look nice with the packages.

Comment: It is very difficult to satisfy these three constraints all together because Markdown is somehow designed for HTML, which means most Markdown tools are built upon web toolchain that has *almost nothing to do with TeX*. I would suggest you investigate if MathJAX is available within VS Code, because it supports macro definition.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://gist.github.com/3846masa/cde99a18a8d7ad225cf7

Comment: Rmarkdown in Rstudio can include any  LaTeX maths (true LaTeX maths, not MathJack), any latex macro and any LateX packages to produce PDF outputs via LaTeX  (for HTML or Word outputs is another story, obviously) and there are not live preview of the whole document (always a bad idea except in very small documents)  but optionally can show in "live pop ups" the WYSIWYG version of a maths formula while you are writing (i.e, while you have the cursor in the formula) without compiling, that is faster.  If you are interested, I can explain in more detail in an answer.